# Elite Knight set vs Faraam Knight set

Tags: dark-souls-2

Which of these two armor sets would be the best to upgrade to +10?

I'm having a hard time comparing them.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about how you would personally judge which is "best"? Without knowing what you're looking for in a set of armor, it might be tough to answer this.

Comment: @Panic Bomb - Since both armor sets are fairly similar in what they have (No petrification or curse resistances) and their purpose, I believe the comparison can be done, but I agree that a bit more information would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a basic comparison between those two armor sets (for those that do not have numbers at hand):

***Helmet***

EKS Helmet Def: 40

EKS Helmet Def +10: 80

FKS Helmet Def: 47

FKS Helmet Def +10: 95

***Chest***

EKS Chest Def: 104

EKS Chest Def +10: 207

FKS Chest Def: 124

FKS Chest Def +10: 249

***Gloves***

EKS GlovesDef: 33

EKS GlovesDef +10: 66

FKS GlovesDef: 46

FKS GlovesDef +10: 93

***Legggings***

EKS LegggingsDef: 61

EKS LegggingsDef +10: 122

FKS LegggingsDef: 78

FKS LegggingsDef +10: 156

***EKS Total Weight and Defense***

Total Weight: 26.8

Total Defense +10: 475

***FKS Total Weight and Defense***

Total Weight: 30

Total Defense +10: 593

Both armor sets have very similar weight but regarding stats they start showing a significant difference when they are upgraded, in the end I see the Faraam set to be superior due to the cost benefit, the reason for this is that the Faraam Knight Set weighs 3.2 more than the Elite Knight Set but for 118 extra armor, better resitances and a superior durability compared to the Elite Knight Set (Faraam KS has 400 durability vs 85 of the Elite KS).

Comment: Where did you locate the stats for this comparison?  Would be handy for me to compare what armor to work with.

Comment: @miR - I got all  the info from one of my characters, just went for a new Faraam armor to check the basic stats. Either way I think you can benefit from the Fextralife Wiki, here's the [link](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Armor#.U2j2FPl5NZs)